# Create Intersection Type of Multiple Generic Types

Tags: typescript, generics

I've been doing a lot of reading into variadic types and some of the new tuple stuff in TypeScript but am having trouble determining if what I'm trying to accomplish is simply not possible given the language capabilities currently.

The exact issue with the API currently can be seen here:

```
export type Themed<T> = { theme: T };

export type ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P, T> = (
  allProps: Partial<P> & Themed<T>
) => string;

export function augmentComponent<
  P,
  TA extends T,
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  T extends object,
  O extends object = {},
  A extends keyof any = never
>(
  styledComponent: StyledComponent<C, T, O, A>,
  styleAugmentation: ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P, TA>
): StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<P>, A> {
  const augmented = styled(styledComponent)`
    ${styleAugmentation}
  `;

  return augmented as StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<P>, A>;
}

export function multiAugment<
  P1 extends {},
  TA1 extends T,
  P2 extends {},
  TA2 extends T,
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  T extends object,
  O extends object = {},
  A extends keyof any = never
>(
  styledComponent: StyledComponent<C, T, O, A>,
  styleAugmentations: [ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P1, TA1>, ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P2, TA2>]
): StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<P1 & P2>, A> {
  const augmented = styled(styledComponent)`
    ${styleAugmentations}
  `;

  return augmented as StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<P1 & P2>, A>;
}
```

In `augmentComponent` the important part of the signature is here: `O & Partial<P>`.

In `multiAugment` which explicitly takes a tuple of two `ThemeStyleAugmentationFun` it's here: `O & Partial<P1 & P2>`

I would like to be able to write a version of multiAugment that can take an arbitrary list of AugmentationFn and union them all together such that it would support any arity. Something that might return a version of `O & Partial<P1 & P2 & P3 ... & P100>` for example.

I'd like to avoid if possible needing to have a massive number of function overloads in order to support this as I could continue writing Tupled versions of increasing length.

Comment: Could you please make a _minimal, complete, and verifiable example_ out of it? It will be easier to reason about your problem without all these dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be sure because I don't have the libraries you're using installed, but perhaps you could do something like this:

```
type PfromSA<SA extends Array<ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, any>>>
  = { [K in keyof SA]: SA[K] extends ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<infer P, any> ? (x: P) => void : never } extends
  { [k: number]: (x: infer P) => void } ? P : never;

type SAExtendsTProperly<SA extends Array<ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, any>>, T>
  = { [K in keyof SA]: SA[K] extends ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, infer U> ? [U] extends [T] ? SA[K] : ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, T> : never }

export function multiAugment<
  SA extends Array<ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, any>>,
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  T extends object,
  O extends object = {},
  A extends keyof any = never
>(
  styledComponent: StyledComponent<C, T, O, A>,
  ...styleAugmentations: SA & SAExtendsTProperly<SA, T>
): StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<PfromSA<SA>>, A> {
  const augmented = styled(styledComponent)`
    ${styleAugmentations}
  `;

  return augmented as StyledComponent<C, T, O & Partial<PfromSA<SA>>, A>;
}
```

The idea is that you use a [generic rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) for your `styleAugmentations` parameter (in the above example I made it a rest parameter instead of a tuple; TypeScript will not infer a tuple type from an array literal, but it will infer a tuple type from a rest parameter.  If you need an array literal you will need to assert or otherwise coax the compiler into interpreting it as a tuple).

This type parameter `SA` is an array of `ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, any>`.  Then the type function `PfromSA<SA>` uses [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to calculate your desired intersection of `P` types from `SA`.  And the type function `SAExtendsTProperly<SA>` does something similar to make sure that each element's `ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P, TA>` has `TA` properly extending `T` (because `ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<P, TA>` might be invariant in `TA`, you can't just make sure `SA extends ThemedStyleAugmentationFn<any, T>`; you have to walk through the tuple and grab the `TA` for each element).

This *should* work as you want, but again, I can't be sure without more self-contained code.

Hope that helps you.  Good luck.

Comment: Wow those are some mind bending type signatures... But it's doing exactly what I needed. Will definitely take some time to digest how it all works put together but thanks a lot. That's incredibly impressive